# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor thread run method execute final block without completing the try block

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I'm creating a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor that execute in given period. I implement following code to check the memory leak or GC overload exception. When running this application with jvm parameter `-Xms4m -Xmx10m`, it executes finally block without completing the try block statement.

I read an [article](https://blog.kapsi.de/blog/canceling-scheduledfutures-memory-leak) about CANCELING SCHEDULEDFUTURES (MEMORY LEAK) and try to replicate.

```
public class ThreadScheduling {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        new Scheduling().run();
    }
}
```

---

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Scheduling extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        start();
    }

    /**
     * https://blog.kapsi.de/blog/canceling-scheduledfutures-memory-leak
     *
     * @param nameFormat
     * @param useDaemonThreads
     * @param poolSize
     * @return
     **/
    public ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduledExecutor(String nameFormat, boolean useDaemonThreads, int poolSize) {

        final RejectedExecutionHandler handler = new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy();

        final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                .setNameFormat(nameFormat)
                .setDaemon(useDaemonThreads)
                .build();

        final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor =
                new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, threadFactory, handler);

        return executor;
    }

    public void start() {

        final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor =
                scheduledExecutor(" executor %s", false, 1);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(new Date() + " Going to execute service.");
                    String s = new String();
                    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ )
                    {
                        s += "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss" +
                                "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss";

                    }
                    System.out.println(new Date() + " service completed.");

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(new Date() + " Error during executing services");
                } finally {
                    executor.purge();
                    System.out.println(new Date() + " Finalize service.");
                }
            }
        }, 2, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

---

Output:

```
Mon Nov 27 19:22:55 IST 2017 Going to execute service.
Mon Nov 27 19:23:18 IST 2017 Finalize service.
```

How  `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` execute run method without completing the CPU bound task?

GC automatically manage required memory, if the heap is less than the required memory.

Is heap memory automatically free by ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in every periodic execution of thread?

Comment: I suggest you try working with a standard amount of heap such as a few GB before trying to make the heap super small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are running out of memory which triggers an OutOfMemoryError which is not an Exception. This means all you see is the output of the `finally` class.

NOTE: In this code

```
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
```

A `Future` object is returned which captures any uncaught Exception or Error. If you discard this you won't see the Error.

> How  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor execute run method without completing the CPU bound task?

If the task throws an Error or Exception it completes without finishing its task.

> GC automatically manage required memory, if the heap is less than the required memory.

And it keeps below the 10 MB limit you set, which means it will throw an OutOfMemoryError if you try to exceed this. (Or if you get too close in some cases)

> Is heap memory automatically free by ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor in every periodic execution of thread?

Heap memory is freed when the GC runs and any object without a strong reference can be cleaned up.

In your case, you don't have enough memory to run the task once so it errors and is not run again.

NOTE: you can tell memory was freed, otherwise you wouldn't see the log message in the `finally` block as this uses memory to print. This won't work if there is no free memory.

BTW

```
executor.purge();
```

Only removes cancelled tasks in the queue. Your task is neither cancelled nor in the queue when it is running.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `RuntimeException`.

```
catch (Exception ex) 
    System.out.println(new Date() + " Error during executing services");
catch (RuntimeException ex)
    System.out.println(new Date() + " Error during executing services");
```

Comment: You need to add some `{` `}` to make it syntactically correct